# unity3d - how to control the movement of the main Camera in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am trying to make an mobile application that contains AR(Augumented Reality)-Mode using Unity3D. So I have connected my mobile device with my unity3d program, and the camera works fine. But when move the mobile device, the main camera inside unity program does not move the same orbit that the mobile device moves. Does any one know how to change or control the orbit of the main Camera in unity3d?

Comment: are you using the acceleration? and you should post some code so people will be able to guide you in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening due to a number of reasons. It could be due to non centered pivots, or coordinate systems for example.

Could you please specify which AR system are you using? As a side note, at work we recently had a project involving Unity3d and Metaio and it was a nightmare to bend the system to do what we needed, specially when we needed to do a lot of object positioning based on the local coordinate system.

When you refer to the orbit of the camera, I imagine it could be that the pivot of the camera is somehow offset and the camera is rotating around that offset. Or maybe that the camera is a child of the actual Game Object that is controlled by the AR system, in which case this parent node acts as a pivot to the camera.

In the picture below you can see that the camera is away from that center point and when it rotates it does it based on that center point, in other words the camera always tries to look at that center point and it gives that feeling of "orbiting" when it moves.

Here's the link to the image (I can't post pictures yet on this forum -.- )
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIcY2.png

Answer (score -1):

To control the movement of the main camera in Unity3D, you can use a combination of scripting and input handling. Here is a simple example:

1. Create a new C# script in Unity and attach it to your main camera GameObject.
2. In the script, declare some variables to control the camera movement:

```cs
public float movementSpeed = 5f;
public float rotationSpeed = 150f;
```

3. In the Update() method of your script, check for input from the player and update the camera's position and rotation accordingly:

```cs
void Update()
{
    // Move camera forward/backward
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveVertical * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // Move camera left/right
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    transform.Translate(Vector3.right * moveHorizontal * movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    // Rotate camera left/right
    float rotateCamera = Input.GetAxis("Rotation");
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * rotateCamera * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

4. In the Unity Editor, select your main camera GameObject and add a Rigidbody component if it doesn't have one already. This ensures that the camera can be moved using physics properties.
5. Set up the input axes in the Unity Input Manager. Go to Edit -> Project Settings -> Input Manager. Create new axes for "Vertical", "Horizontal", and "Rotation" (or modify existing axes if you prefer).
6. Test and tweak the movement and rotation speeds in the script until you have the desired control over the camera.

With these steps, you should now have control over the movement and rotation of your main camera in Unity3D.